# Библиотека для работы с JPEG и EXIF в коммерческом ПО

Tags: c++, c, jpeg, поиск-библиотек, exif

Меня интересует библиотека для работы с JPEG и поддержкой Exif. Быстрый поиск дает libjpeg (поддержка exif отсутствует). И отдельные GPL решения для работы с exif (exiv2, libexif). Может у кого-нибудь был опыт работы с exif?

P.S. Как вариант можно в принципе доработать libjpeg, но что-то в старом сишном проекте не сильно хочется ковыряться

Comment: а чем LGPL'ный libexif не устраивает?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а разве LGPL libexif позволяет линковать зависимую либу статически?

Comment: @LmTinyToon, вообще говоря, не совсем.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). Она много чего умеете, имеет связки для многих популярных языков и распространяется под [Apache 2.0](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php).

Comment: Я как понял, подразумевается возможность использовать биндинг Magick++. Спасибо за наводку, попытаюсь поиграться с библиотекой

Comment: @LmTinyToon, как угодно. Можно использовать библиотеку, можно использовать утилиту из своего приложения (т.е. добавлять системный вызов). Я использовал библиотеку, когда мне это было нужно. Всё довольно просто и библиотека достаточно богата на функционал.